# Weird audio issues on dell latitude rugged 14 (5414)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell

I am having some weird audio issues on my dell latitude 5414. The laptop only has one speaker inside, yet Ubuntu thinks that there is stereo audio. Audio only from the left channel will play from this speaker, not any audio from the right channel. This issue does not happen with headphones. I thought of forcing the the system to output mono audio through the speaker, but I have no idea on how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what release of Ubuntu you're asking about (also likely a desktop release, but it's best if we're told).

Comment: @guiverc I am on Ubuntu 20.10